# Why getLastRow method is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using Google Sheet, data were entered into cells before the data gets transferred into a 'database' page.

Problem:
1) After the transfer completed, previous entries were replaced by the new entries.
2) Database would start at a different row (i.e. row 35) instead of row 1.

Question: What caused the two problems, and how to solve the problems?

Below is my script. Thanks in advance!

```js
function setValue(cellName, value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

function getValue(cellName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
}

function getNextRow() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() + 1;
}

function addTrade(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) {
  var row = getNextRow();
  setValue('Meta4!B' + row, a);
  setValue('Meta4!C' + row, b);
  setValue('Meta4!D' + row, c);
  setValue('Meta4!E' + row, d);
  setValue('Meta4!F' + row, e);
  setValue('Meta4!G' + row, f);
  setValue('Meta4!H' + row, g);
}

function submitTrade() {
 addTrade(new Date(), getValue('Dashboard!N3'), getValue('Dashboard!N4'),  getValue('Dashboard!N5'), getValue('Dashboard!N6'), getValue ('Dashboard!N7'), getValue('Dashboard!N8'));

 var app = SpreadsheetApp;
 var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 activeSheet.getRange('Dashboard!N3:O8').clearContent();
 }
```

Comment: There aren't enough details to answer your questions, like how are the script being run and the context (which sheet is the active sheet).

Answer (score 1):

#### Possible Issues:

- `getLastRow` executed on a incorrect sheet
- Possible datavalidation dropdowns/unrecognised values  up to row 35
- Code repeats

#### Solutions

- Get sheet first and then execute `getLastRow`
- Remove Data validations  from sheet
- Use DRY principle

#### Flow:

- Get source sheet values as a array, add current date to it and transpose the array.
- Get lastRow from target sheet and setValues the modified array.

#### Sample Script:

```
function transposeWithDate() {

  var cfg = {
    ssh: 'Dashboard',//sourceSheet
    sRng: 'N3:N8',//sourceRange
    tsh: 'Meta4',//targetSheet
    dt: new Date(),
  };

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName(cfg.ssh);
  var values = source.getRange(cfg.sRng).getValues(); //[[1],[2],[3]]
  var target = ss.getSheetByName(cfg.tsh);
  var lastRow = target.getLastRow();
  values.unshift([cfg.dt]); //add Date
  var transposedVal = [ //transpose values [[date,1,2,3]]
    values.map(function(e) {
      return e[0];
    }),
  ];
  target
    .getRange(lastRow + 1, 2, transposedVal.length, transposedVal[0].length)
    .setValues(transposedVal);
}
```

#### References:

- [Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)
- [Array#Unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)
- [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)
- [DRY Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)